# iOS Wifi Signal Strength

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6, wifi

I have an Enterprise app (no app store review) and I'd like to get the current strength of the wifi signal.  This is for troubleshooting purposes, where I'd like to determine the actual wifi signal strength at the time we log a message or error.

I can use a private API, but would prefer a supported method.  I've found a few examples pointing to Stumbler, but this appears to be outdated.